# Level sets of a gaussian

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scientific-computing

I would like to plot the level sets of this 2-arguments function :

```
def xi_gaussian_x(x,y):
        sigma = 0.8
        mu = 1.2
        return (1.0/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi)))*(np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2*sigma**2)))
```

where x and y are between -pi and pi. My code is the following :

```
plt.ion()
xInterval = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,num=1000)
yInterval = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,num=1000)
levels_xi_gaussian_x=np.zeros((len(xInterval),len(yInterval)))
for i in range(len(xInterval)):
        for j in range(len(yInterval)):
              levels_xi_gaussian_x[i,j]=xi_gaussian_x(xInterval[i],yInterval[j])
plt.figure()
c = plt.contour(xInterval,yInterval,levels_xi_gaussian_x.T,50)
```

Even if I increase the resolution of the x and y intervals, I still get regions in the -pi,pi plane which are empty : 
[image]
How can I make all the plane be filled with vertical lines ?

Comment: Just use `plt.contourf`.

Comment: A Gaussian is flat on top (mu=1.2)  and very shallow on the bottom. So the image you got  is to be expected. If you want levels then you certainly don't want to fill the image with levels so tightly that individual levels can't be seen, as you already have on the slopes. In the y-axis you have no variation. Did you mean to plot as function of `mu` and `sigma`?

Comment: My function has in general two arguments (which are angles by the way). There is this special example I am working on, for which this function depends only on the first argument x. So no, I don't want to plot my function against mu or sigma. Actually, I thought about a gaussian because I wanted a function that has high level sets between x=0.6 and x=1.7 and progressively smaller values as it it goes far from this region. I could use any other smooth function that verifies this criterion.

Comment: Well the plot you get is exactly what I would have expected looking at your code. You can increase the density of levels further, but then you won't see any levels.